# Does increasing RAM correct my bottlenecking CPU

Tags: windows-7, memory, performance, desktop-computer

So these are my system Specs

```
MSI GTX 1050 Ti 4GB GPU

Hyper X Blue 8GB DDR3 2100 MHz

Intel i5 4440 processor

Gigabyte h81m-ds2

Seasonic S1211 Bronze 80+ PSU
```

I'm playing Resident Evil 7 and it bottlenecks in that game heavily.
At some games, I experience a very minimal lag (etc. PUBG)

So I'm wondering, should I go and buy another 8GB DDR3 ram?

I am also thinking of upgrading my computer some time soon (maybe after this year) so I would want to save some cash for my next big buy, but still, If adding a RAM would solve my issue, then I think I may hold on to this unit for some 4 years more.

Comment: How did you determine what the bottleneck is? Additional RAM will in no way speed up your CPU.

Comment: I asked a question here too, and they pointed out that my CPU is too slow for my GPU, thus the bottleneck.

Comment: If you have been told your CPU is the problem, why are you asking, if additional memory will help?  Additional memory will not help with latency.  The recommended specifications only indicate 8 GB.  So it is very unlikely additional memory will help with the performance of Resident Evil 7.  The  problem is that although you have 4 GB of VRAM your **GPU** is a bottlekneck due to the 1060 being the recommended.  There is a huge difference between the 1050 and the 1060.  You exceed the recommended specifications for PUBG.

Comment: Worth pointing out the specifications for games are only going to increase.  Your CPU will not cut it after this year, your GPU despite being the current generation, is going to struggle with some of the better games.  Additional memory will not help in a case like yours, whom ever told you that your CPU is "too slow for your GPU", doesn't understand your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound I do know that my GPU and CPU needs upgrading, and I have plans to upgrade them next year. I'm asking this because I'm thinking, maybe RAM can help about the load in the CPU? dont worry about PUBG, its very minimal to none, but, am I correct with my assumption?

Comment: @Mr.J - Your system already meets the memory requirements of Resident Evil 7, additional memory, WILL NOT help with the performance of that program.  Additionally memory will bring you absolutely no performance increase with regards to that program.  I spent over 5 minutes wording my comment the way I did, I would appreciate it, if you would read it.  I feel like I am repeating myself.

Comment: @Ramhound now I'm confuse even more... I will check for other information about my problem, thank you!

Comment: @Mr.J - **Your performance problems with Resident Evil 7 are due to not meeting the requirements with regards to the GPU.** You likely simply have the settings to high for your system.  You meet the recommended specifications with regards to the CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Additional memory does not make your CPU any faster.

A non-technical analogy would be 'If I have a car with a weak engine will it ride faster if fold down my rear seats so I have more cargo space'. The answer to which should be obvious.

What may be confusing is that adding more memory often makes the system faster, but **NOT** if the application is CPU bound.

Comment: So the answer maybe overclocking? (well, I cant overclock my CPU can I) or better yet replacement right?

Comment: @Mr.J the answer is correct - don’t change the question...